# T-SQL sp_xml_preparedocument creates empty table

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, sql-server-2012, xml-parsing

I'm using SQL Server 2012 and using the system stored procedures `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` to parse the XML in my source table `[XML_Source]`

This is my code.

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX) 

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM dbo.[XML_Source]

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT *
INTO dbo.[XML_Destination]
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'OutcomesData/Outcome/Household_Info/Household_Member_Info')
WITH (
Household_ID [varchar](100) '../@ID',
Team [varchar](100) '../Team',
Address1 [varchar](100) '../Address1',
Address2 [varchar](100) '../Address2',
Address3 [varchar](100) '../Address3',
Postcode [varchar](10) '../Postcode'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

However, when I execute the above, nothing is input into [XML_Destination].  I 100% have data stored as XML in [XML_Source].  What am I missing or where can I be looking?

Comment: Why do you want t use these old stored procedures, which are really just there for backward compatibility, and not XQUERY?

Comment: I'm not familiar with XQUERY - but I'm guessing I can achieve the same with XQUERY?

Comment: @Michael, please edit your original post and add DDL and sample data population.

Answer (score 1):

if you can provide you test XML then, I will provide a better answer.

Otherwise, try this :

```
DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX) 
-- it test XML
SELECT @XML = '<OutcomesData>
                    <Outcome>
                        <Household_Info>
                            <Household_Member_Info>
                                <Household_ID>1</Household_ID>
                                <Team>1</Team>
                                <Address1>Surat</Address1>
                                <Address2>Gujarat</Address2>
                                <Address3>India</Address3>
                            </Household_Member_Info>
                        </Household_Info>
                    </Outcome>
                </OutcomesData>'

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT * 
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'OutcomesData/Outcome/Household_Info/Household_Member_Info',2)
WITH (
    Household_ID varchar(100),
    Team         varchar(100),
    Address1     varchar(100),
    Address2     varchar(100),
    Address3     varchar(100),
    Postcode     varchar(10)
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```